# iOS13 UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass not receiving collectionView frame changes

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, ios13, flowlayout

I am testing out some code and it looks like in iOS13 the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not receiving the changes in the collectionView frame.

Below is a sample code, in which I simply change the height of the collectionView based on the amount I scroll inthe tableview below the collectionView:

ViewController

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {  
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()  

    let totalScroll = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height  
    let offset = (scrollView.contentOffset.y)  
    let percentage = offset / totalScroll  

    var frame = collectionView.frame  
    frame.size.height = 40 - (40 * percentage)  
    collectionView.frame = frame  
  }
```

CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```swift
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {  
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)  
    print(collectionView?.frame)  
    return attributes  
  }
```

The print statement inside the CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout in iOS 12 and below prints out the changes in collectionView.frame correctly i.e. the height actually changes. But in iOS 13, it isn't being reflected at all.

Help anybody?

Comment: Not sure if its related but we found that `traitCollectionDidChange` and `viewWillTransition` are no longer called on view load in iOS 13-- we had to move some logic into `viewDidLoad` for initial setup. More info here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_13_release_notes

Answer (score 3):

First of all,

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    ...
}
```

looks suspicious. Are you sure that your layout should be invalidated inside the `scrollViewDidScroll` function?

There is a proper place where a layout should be invalidated while scrolling:

```
final class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        // proper place to invalidate layout while scrolling
    }
}
```

If you invalidate your layout inside the layout class you will be able to calculate the desired layout container height properly. And then you can inform your collection view that its height should be changed. For example, with the help of some delegate:

```
protocol CustomCollectionViewFlowLayoutSizeDelegate: class {

    func newSizeAvailableFor(layout: CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout, progress: CGFloat)
}

final class CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    weak var sizeDelegate: CustomCollectionViewFlowLayoutSizeDelegate?

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        // proper place to invalidate layout while scrolling
    }
}

final class CustomViewController: CustomCollectionViewFlowLayoutSizeDelegate {

    func newSizeAvailableFor(layout: CustomCollectionViewFlowLayout, progress: CGFloat) {
        // change collectionView frame
    }
}
```

Conclusion:

Your layout is trying to listen to its container height, but its container height is calculated based on your layout. You can easily drop the container dependency for height calculation or just provide the layout with initial container height. In the end the layout will be responsible for all the calculations.

Comment: turns out the solution was simply to use view.layer.frame instead of view.frame directly.

Rest of the code was left untouched :)

Comment: @Karthik well... it might be a solution in a particular case. But, it is always a good way to find a more general approach.